# Print a report directly on a thermal printer

Tags: delphi, printing, report, delphi-xe6, thermal-printer

I have to print a report directly on a thermal printer POS58 and I am using FortesReport 4.0 and Delphi XE6.
How to print all the content on a single page, whose height increases according to the content (without generating more than one page)? TRLReport has a property for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a typical paper size(letter) and set it margins(top and bottom) to 0. Print that directly to the thermal paper, no special calls needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Report.UnLimitedHeight property to True. This should print all data on a single page with unlimited page height.